# Size and position of array

Tags: positioning, arrays

The following is an extract from my LaTeX file which describes a `table`. The table has a fair amount of space below it. I would, therefore, like to increase the `arraystretch`. However, by increasing it slightly, the table moves to the next page.

Why does LaTeX think the table is too big for the first page? How can I force it to put the table right after the text?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,fullpage,microtype,hyperref,subfig,hypcap,amsfonts,parskip,multirow,titlesec}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{20pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{2pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{16pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{2pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}

\widowpenalty=2000
\clubpenalty=2000
\hyphenpenalty=400
\interfootnotelinepenalty=400
\DisableLigatures{encoding=*,family=*}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}

\begin{document}

\section{Payoff Matrix}
\label{sec:Payoff Matrix}

From the brief description in section~\ref{sec:Model and Assumptions} and the full description of section~\ref{sec:Extensive Form}, it is straight forward to create the payoff matrix, which shows the expected payoff to the sender and to the receiver as a function of their strategies.

\vspace{6mm}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.05}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l||lr|lr}
 &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{AA}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{AK}\\
\hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{GGGG}& &$1$& &$1$\\
&&&&\\
 &$p$& &$p$& \\
\hline
\multirow{7}{*}{GGGB}& &$p(1-e_{1})+$& &$p(1-e_{1})+$\\
 & &$p(e_{1})(1-e_{3})+$& &$p(e_{1})(1-e_{3})+$\\
 & &$(1-p)(e_{1})+$& &$(1-p)(e_{2})+$\\
 & &$(1-p)(1-e_{1})(1-e_{3})$& &$(1-p)(1-e_{2})(e_{3})$\\
&&&&\\
 &$p(1-e_{1})+$& &$p(1-e_{1})+$& \\
 &$p(e_{3})(1-e_{3})+$& &$p(e_{1})(1-e_{3})+$& \\
 &$(1-p)(1-e_{1})(e_{3})$& &$(1-p)(1-e_{2})(e_{3})$& \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{GGBB}& &$p(1-e_{1})+$& &$p(1-e_{1})$\\
 & &$(1-p)(e_{1})$& &$(1-p)(e_{2})$\\
&&&&\\
 &$1-e_{1}$& &$p(1-e_{1})+$& \\
 &$ $& &$(1-p)(1-e_{2})$& \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{GBGB}& &$x$& &$x$\\
 & &$x$& &$x$\\
&&&&\\
 &$x$& &$x$& \\
 &$x$& &$x$& \\
\hline
\multirow{7}{*}{GBBB}& &$x$& &$x$\\
 & &$x$& &$x$\\
 & &$x$& &$x$\\
 & &$x$& &$x$\\
&&&&\\
 &$x$& &$x$& \\
 &$x$& &$x$& \\
 &$x$& &$x$& \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{BBBB}& &$0$& &$0$\\
&&&&\\
 &$1-p$& &$1-p$& 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{The payoff matrix}
\label{eq:Label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\begin{table}[h!]` places it on the first page with a `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.19}`. Beyond that it does not fit on the first page.

Comment: That's great - exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks.